# Calculate scaled coordinate

Tags: geometry

*I got 2 Squares with the following corner coordinates.*

**Square 1:**
(-128,-128)
(128,128)

**Square 2:**
(0,0)
(512,512)

How can I calculate a coordinate inside Square 2 and translate it to the scaled coordinate of Square 1. For instance the coordinate (0,0) in Square 2, which coordinate is this in Square 1? this should be technically be (-128,-128), but in my calculations it result in (0,0) [Delta x of both, divide square 2 by 1 and divide the coordinate by this number]

Comment: I've tried to divide delta x of square 2 with square 1, which is 40/10=4
after that I divide the coordinate with 4 which results in (0,0), but this doesn't work with other coordinates and negative values.

Comment: Are you sure that those are corresponding vertices? For example, they may be adjacent in Square 1 but opposite in Square 2. Are the transformation required to be linear/affine? Are you sure that the image of $(0,0)$ is $(0,0)$? Without that fact, the answer does not appear to be unique.

Comment: I took it to mean that they are opposite corners. OP, is that right? Then can you show us one point that didn't work?

Comment: I've changed the question it to the current situation where my problem occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is correct. You just have to add $(-128,-128)$ to the coords you have found.

More generally, you have calculated the position in Square 1 relative to its bottom left corner, so you have to add the coords of the bottom left corner to the values you have discovered and all will be well.

Even more generally, suppose your two squares are:

Square 1: opposite corners are given by $(x_1, y_1) (x_1+d_1, y_1+d_1)$

Square 2: opposite corners are given by $(x_2, y_2) (x_2+d_2, y_2+d_2)$

Suppose we are give a point $P_2$ within Square 2. Let its coordinates be $(x_{P_2},y_{P_2})$

We want to translate this to give a point $P_1$ within Square 1. These new coordinates will be $(x_{P_1},y_{P_1})$

Formula: $x_{P_1}=x_1+\frac {x_{P_2}-x_2}{d_2}d_1$

and: $y_{P_1}=y_1+\frac {y_{P_2}-y_2}{d_2}d_1$

Of course, you might want to consider situations where you have rectangles rather than squares:

Rectangle 1: opposite corners are given by $(x_1, y_1) (x_1+w_1, y_1+h_1)$ where $w_1$ is the width of the rectangle and $h_1$ is the height of the rectangle.

Rectangle 2: opposite corners are given by $(x_2, y_2) (x_2+w_2, y_2+h_2)$

Suppose we are give a point $P_2$ within Rectangle 2. Let its coordinates be $(x_{P_2},y_{P_2})$

We want to translate this to give a point $P_1$ within Rectangle 1. These new coordinates will be $(x_{P_1},y_{P_1})$

Formula: $x_{P_1}=x_1+\frac {x_{P_2}-x_2}{w_2}w_1$ and $y_{P_1}=y_1+\frac {y_{P_2}-y_2}{h_2}h_1$

Example:

Suppose your two squares are:

Square 1: opposite corners are given by $(3, 7) (15, 19)$ ($d_1=12$).

Square 2: opposite corners are given by $(-8, -2) (22, 28)$ ($d_2=30$).

Suppose we are given the point $P_2 (10,7)$

Translate this to give a point $P_1$ within Square 1.

Formula: $x_{P_1}=3+\frac {7--2}{30}12=3+\frac {9}{30}12=6.6$

Comment: But what happens if Square 2 has the cords  (-256,-256) (256,256) now it has no 'offset' of (-128,-128) which make it not 'dynamic' which I need. Do you know if this offset can be calculated?

Comment: In that case the offset would be $(-256, -256)$

Comment: could this be written as a formula, since this feels like a magic value. the way to acquire -128 and -256 can't be done in the same fashion so far I can see.

Comment: Altered answer to accommodate these questions - and more!

Comment: I'm not able to fill in the formula since I'm unclear what the W1 and W2 represents as well if x1 is in this case just -128 or 256 (delta x) Is it possible to create an filled in example of this formula? Thanks already for the information